# Msys2 autocomplete doesn't work for current directory

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete, permissions, msys2

I installed `msys2-x86_64-20161025.exe` following [these steps](http://www.msys2.org/).

When I try autocompletion for programs on the `PATH`, e.g. by typing `g` and then pressing `TAB` key twice, Msys2 console shows me a lot of options (.exe , .dll , and others).

However, when I type `./` and then press `TAB` key twice, it shows me only subdirectories of the current directory, but not `.sh` or `.bat` files in the current directory.

`ls -al` command shows that Msys2 doesn't see "executable" file permission on the `.bat` and `.sh` files. `chmod +x *` doesn't seem to work on Windows.

So how to get autocomplete to work in Msys2 for current directory script files?

I am on Windows 10 x64. Let me know if some additional info about the environment is needed.

Comment: If your script contains a shebang line, msys2 will recognize the file as a script. That's has been my experience at least.

Comment: @nit, yes, adding `#!/bin/bash` works. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: Posted as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your script contains a shebang line, msys2 will recognize the file as a script. That's has been my experience at least.

Particularly for Bash scripts the first line of each script can be `#!/bin/bash`, if Bash is installed in `/bin/`. See more on [Shebang line here](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang).